# How to reset the querySelectorAll number?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, slider, queryselector

I have 5 `li` and the function stops repeating when it reaches the same number of times. I need another function to reset or cancel this number.

This is the code that I have:

```js
let currentIndex = 0;

function toMove() {
  const slider  = document.querySelector('#thumbelina0');
  const element = document.querySelectorAll('li')[currentIndex];
  slider.style.marginLeft = parseInt(slider.style.marginLeft) 
                          - element.offsetWidth - 10 + 'px';
  currentIndex += 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbelina" style="padding:5px;overflow: hidden;">
  <button class="btnToLeft" onclick="toMovel()">
    <
  </button>
  <ul id="thumbelina0" style="padding:0px; width:max-content; text-align:center;display: flex;margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: 0px;">
    <li style="padding:5px;width: auto;height: 100px;display: block;">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.eKE8nrMRCK3bdvd62kWJ_wHaEK%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=5827498e8cb6aac88f508eaf79bab099000b1748a4b93fd8b994b0b3c56c5fe5&ipo=images" style="background-image: url(https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.eKE8nrMRCK3bdvd62kWJ_wHaEK%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=5827498e8cb6aac88f508eaf79bab099000b1748a4b93fd8b994b0b3c56c5fe5&ipo=images)"
        style="margin-top: -5px;margin-left: -5px;" />
    </li>
    <li style="padding:5px;width: auto;height: 100px;display: block;">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP._IgGc9h6kbuSmYLsRhBNvwHaEo%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=10afdedcaa07209003fc91888b567582128374e6578bce7d2448311d0c0893f9&ipo=images" style="background-image: url(https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP._IgGc9h6kbuSmYLsRhBNvwHaEo%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=10afdedcaa07209003fc91888b567582128374e6578bce7d2448311d0c0893f9&ipo=images)"
        style="margin-top: -5px;margin-left: -5px;" />
    </li>
    <li style="padding:5px;width: auto;height: 100px;display: block;">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.eKE8nrMRCK3bdvd62kWJ_wHaEK%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=5827498e8cb6aac88f508eaf79bab099000b1748a4b93fd8b994b0b3c56c5fe5&ipo=images" style="background-image: url(https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.eKE8nrMRCK3bdvd62kWJ_wHaEK%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=5827498e8cb6aac88f508eaf79bab099000b1748a4b93fd8b994b0b3c56c5fe5&ipo=images)"
        style="margin-top: -5px;margin-left: -5px;" />
    </li>
    <li style="padding:5px;width: auto;height: 100px;display: block;">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP._IgGc9h6kbuSmYLsRhBNvwHaEo%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=10afdedcaa07209003fc91888b567582128374e6578bce7d2448311d0c0893f9&ipo=images" style="background-image: url(https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP._IgGc9h6kbuSmYLsRhBNvwHaEo%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=10afdedcaa07209003fc91888b567582128374e6578bce7d2448311d0c0893f9&ipo=images)"
        style="margin-top: -5px;margin-left: -5px;" />
    </li>
    <li style="padding:5px;width: auto;height: 100px;display: block;">
      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.eKE8nrMRCK3bdvd62kWJ_wHaEK%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=5827498e8cb6aac88f508eaf79bab099000b1748a4b93fd8b994b0b3c56c5fe5&ipo=images" style="background-image: url(https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.eKE8nrMRCK3bdvd62kWJ_wHaEK%26pid%3DApi&f=1&ipt=5827498e8cb6aac88f508eaf79bab099000b1748a4b93fd8b994b0b3c56c5fe5&ipo=images)"
        style="margin-top: -5px;margin-left: -5px;" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button class="btnToRight" onclick="toMove()">
    >
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are implementing carousel feature to show different images.
You can use conditional statement to reset the `currentIndex` to `0` when it reaches last index of array.

```
function toMove() {
  const slider  = document.querySelector('#thumbelina0');
  const element = document.querySelectorAll('li');

  // 1. Get the length of array
  const numOfElements = element.length;

  slider.style.marginLeft = parseInt(slider.style.marginLeft) 
                          - element.offsetWidth - 10 + 'px';

  currentIndex += 1;

  // 2. Reset if index reaches last element's index
  if (currentIndex === numOfElements-1)
        currentIndex=0;
}
```

Comment: When implementing this the code does not even work

Comment: It is just an example of the answer showing the way how it can be implemented. It is not entire solution. When the index is intialized, you have to reset the margin according to it.

Comment: And can you give me a complete solution?